# Removed .php extension of url, but not working on right click

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, right-click

I have edited my **.htaccess** file succesfully, by writing this code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

This enables me to get rid of the `.php` extension on my url. The problem now is that if I right click on a element of my website, I still see the .php url. If I remove it manually, the site is still visible, so the code works very well I guess, but how can I solve the "right-click issue" too?

**PS: a second question... Does this effect the SEO of my website in any way?**

Comment: Where do you see the .php?  Do you have an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the code of your pages still contains *links* to your `.php` pages, containing the extension. You can easily get rid of them by modifying your own code to remove `.php` from the ends of links or asset names. (And no, this won't affect SEO at all.)